# PHP Session Variables Dropped Between Controllers

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller, authentication

So the problem is, when /MVCTest/manage/dashboard is called, the authenticator is failing because authenticate (a method in the authenticator class) is not finding $_SESSION['user_id'], so it kicks the user back to the login page.

However, if I change the action below to:
action="/MVCTest/manage/login?target=MVCTest/manage/dashboard"

and add the same login function form the index controller to the manageController, everything works fine, but this means I would have to have a login function in every controller that has a page I want to login from (which is every page since I want a user dashboard).

So how do I get the $_SESSION to presist between controllers so I can have a single controller responsible for logging a user in/out?

First, some code...

action="/MVCTest/index/login?target=MVCTest/manage/dashboard" calls the login action of the indexController.

```
<?php
  Class indexController Extends Core_Controller {

    public function login(){
     $this->registry->authenticator->login($_POST);
    }
  }
?>
```

The authenticator object was created  in the bootstrap and assigned to the registry.  Now for the authenticator object.

```
<?php
  Class Authenticator Extends Base_Model {

    public function login($credentials){
  //Select user from the database based on email/username
  try{
    $STH = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
    $STH->bindParam(1, $credentials['login']);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $credentials['login']);
    $STH->execute();
    while($user = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
      $password = $user->user_salt.$credentials['password'];
      $password = $this->hashData($password);
      try{
        if($password === $user->password){
          //Active and Verified user exists, set sessions
          $random = $this->generateRandomString();
          //Build the token
          $token = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] . $random;
          $token = $this->hashData($token);

          //Setup session variables
          session_start();
          $_SESSION["token"] = $token;
          $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user->id;

          //Delete old session records for the user
          $STH = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM user_session WHERE user_account_id = ?");
          $STH->bindParam(1, $user->id);
          $STH->execute();

          //Insert new session records for the user
          try{
            $STH = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_session (user_account_id, session_id, token) 
                                       VALUES (?,'".session_id()."', ?);");
            $STH->bindParam(1, $user->id);
            $STH->bindParam(2, $token);
            $STH->execute();
            header("Location: /{$_GET['target']}");
            exit;
          } catch (PDOException $e){
            file_put_contents(__SITE_PATH."/logs/errors/MySQLErrors", $e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
            die($e->getMessage());
          }                
        } else {
          throw new Exception("Password is incorrect!");
        }
      } catch (Exception $e){
        file_put_contents(__SITE_PATH."/logs/errors/LoginErrors", $e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    }
    //Email/Username not found
    throw new Exception("Email/Username not found!");
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    file_put_contents(__SITE_PATH."/logs/errors/LoginErrors", $e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    die($e->getMessage());
  } catch (PDOException $e){
    file_put_contents(__SITE_PATH."/logs/errors/MySQLErrors", $e->getMessage()."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
}      
}
?>
```

And finally, my manageController

```
<?php
  session_name();
  session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/MVCTest/manage/");
  session_start();

  Class manageController Extends Core_Controller {

    public function index() {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        header("Location: /MVCTest/manage/dashboard");
        exit;
      }
      $this->registry->template->show('manage/index');
    }

    public function dashboard(){
      $this->registry->authenticator->authenticate("/MVCTest/manage/");     
      $this->registry->template->show('manage/dashboard');
    }
  }
?>
```

I found the answer.  Leave session_name(); 
  session_set_cookie_params(3600, __SITE_PATH.'/MVCTest/manage/'); in the manageController while moving session_start(); to the beginning of the extended Core_Controller while adding a public login function.

The result is that every page can log somebody in; however, I feel like this is bad practice.  The problem I see is that every single page call will start a session regardless of if the user is logged in or not.  I get the feeling that this is bad, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
//Setup session variables
session_start();
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user->id;
```

You must use

```
session_start();
```

At the beginning of the file.

Read more about [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)